# Mongoose: how to prevent null values being added to array of ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Title says it all. Below is a schema property definition that I thought would work, but doesn't do the job. I figured `required: true` on the type object should work?

```
  users: {
    type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          required: true
        }
    ],
    default: []
  }
```

the following query allows a `null` value to be added to the array:

`MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$addToSet: {users: ['']}})`

Answer (score 1):

aaaaaaaand, of course as soon as I post to SO, i find the answer for myself. need to set option `runValidators: true` on update...

This is the real reason I post to SO, its like always carrying an umbrella, its guaranteed not to rain.